# What am I missing? CasperJS web scraping returning NULL

Tags: cookies, web-scraping, screen-scraping, casperjs

This is perplexing to me. I've got a casperJS script that scrapes pages just fine. But this one page returns null. This page (like others) is behind a cookied session.

If I log the URL that it hits, and punch that into the web browser, I get the XML result. http://cl.ly/1d0A160o0Q2f

But inside casperJS it is null for the result.

```
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo(this.getPageContent());
});
```

That URL is the URL that works in the browser. And I've confirmed that at that point in the code Casper does have a valid cookie session. This URL is normally an AJAX call but works fine from the browser as a GET request. I don't know what I'm missing with Casper that would cause this to be NULL. I must be missing something.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Ill check those out. Using phantom 1.9.8 (2.* fails for me) and casper 1.1.0-beta5

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors for the URL i'm trying to hit. I see 2 other operation cancelled but they seem unrelated.